# How to check the file usage summary in Google Drive

Tags: google-drive

After sharing the folder/file in Google Drive to some other mail address, how can I monitor the log activity, like when the respective user has accessed the file, what are the modifications done etc.?

Is this possible in Google Drive?

Answer (score 1):

It is unfortunately not possible in Google Drive put aside the [revision history](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/190843?hl=en) for Google documents and the [activity stream](http://googledrive.blogspot.com/2014/01/a-new-activity-stream-in-drive-shows.html) (available since January 14, 2014).